# Why is $\dim(K^{\times}/(K^{\times})^2)=1+\dim\frac{R^{\times}}{(R^{\times})^2}$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $R$ be a discrete valuation ring with unites denoted $R^{\times}$. Let $K$ be its fraction field with units denoted $K^{\times}$.

I want to know why

- $K^{\times}/(K^{\times})^n$ is an $\mathbb{F}_n$-vector space ?
- $\dim(K^{\times}/(K^{\times})^2)=1+\dim\frac{R^{\times}}{(R^{\times})^2}$ ?

---

For the first question, note that $K^{\times}/(K^{\times})^n=x+(K^{\times})^n, x \in K^{\times}=\{1+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}~: x \in K^{\times} \}$ for $n$ scalars $a_i$.

For the second question, we note $K^{\times}=R^{\times} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$. Then, $$K^{\times}/(K^{\times})^2=\frac{R^{\times} \oplus \mathbb{Z}}{(R^{\times} \oplus \mathbb{Z})^2}$$
But I could not draw conclusion to both questions.

Thanks

Comment: For the first claim: verify the axioms of a vector space. The second equation does not make sense as it stands; what does $+$ mean here?

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer, for the first question, I don't understand why it is $F_n$ vector space. For the second one, I want to show  $dim(K^{\times}/(K^{\times})^2)=1+dim(\frac{R^{\times}}{(R^{\times})^2})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title is confusing because of the mixing between additive and multiplicative notation.

For any abelian group $G/G^p$ is a $\Bbb{F}_p$-vector space. Then $(G\times H)/(G \times H)^p \cong G/G^p\times H/H^p$. Apply it to $K^\times = R^\times \times \pi^\Bbb{Z}$ (where $(\pi)$ is the maximal ideal of $R$).

Comment: What is $H$ is here ? In my case, $K^{\times}/(K^{\times})^p=(R^{\times} \times \pi^{\mathbb{Z}})/(R^{\times} \times \pi^{\mathbb{Z}})^p \cong R^{\times}/(R^{\times})^p \times \pi^{\mathbb{Z}}/\pi^{p \mathbb{Z}}$. But the last factor $\pi^{\mathbb{Z}}/\pi^{p \mathbb{Z}}$ is $\mathbb{F}_p$. Is it correct ?